# php detect if date given has no day value

Tags: php, date

Say I am given a date like "August 2016" is there a way in PHP to simply find if a date has no day given?

All the PHP functions I can find automatically set a "1" to the day of a date if none is given.

What I want to do is weed out dates that don't give me a day.

They are not provided by me, and can be mixed in UK or US formats.

Comment: could you check for a number at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Do you expect any other date formats? if so, which ones? Can you control the user input? How do you get the values? Please clarify your question so we can help you properly.

Comment: `All the PHP functions I can find automatically set a "1" to the day of a date if none is given.` just use a `DateTime` for that, then set the day manually. what day do you expect if none is given? you can just load it into `DateTime` and ignore the date, you can control whatever you format output after that anyway

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to get some kind of value for a date object that has its day property set to null or undefined. Even if that were possible, how would you imagine other date functions to work with that? Like when you add 1 day to that date? Or 30 days?

Comment: Updated question to be more specific.

Comment: update was not a great help to be honest. source of date? range of possible date formats? use of date? what will you do if it has a day? does not have a day?

Comment: Already have the answer.

Comment: great, next time better question please

Comment: I got the exact answer I needed, so it was apparently good enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$notValid = DateTime::createFromFormat('F Y', '21 January 2016'); // false
$valid = DateTime::createFromFormat('F Y', 'January 2016'); // DateTime object
```

Comment: no need for `createFromFormat`, even the constructor can understand `August 2016`

Comment: @Ghost indeed, you're right, but author of the question wanted to verify if given date has or has not day given. Both `August 2016` and `21 August 2016` will return true, which not what he needs.

Comment: This looks indeed like a nice approach. I would suggest you would turn that into a function that takes a date string and returns the day number if present, and null otherwise.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, it works perfectly to weed out dates that don't give me a day thank you! :)